# How can I fix this error: the following arguments are required: --in-path, --out-path

Tags: python, conda

Here is the error message

```
Hassans-MacBook-Pro-3:fast-style-transfer-master hassan$ python3 evaluate.py --checkpoint ./rain-princess.ckpt --in-path/Users/hassan/Downloads/fast-style-transfer-master--out-path ./output_image.jpg
usage: evaluate.py [-h] --checkpoint CHECKPOINT --in-path IN_PATH --out-path
                   OUT_PATH [--device DEVICE] [--batch-size BATCH_SIZE]
                   [--allow-different-dimensions]
evaluate.py: error: the following arguments are required: --in-path, --out-path
```

this is a part of the evaluate.py script, I was just following a tutorial is the file placed uncorrectly.

```
from __future__ import print_function
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, 'src')
import transform, numpy as np, vgg, pdb, os
import scipy.misc
import tensorflow as tf
from utils import save_img, get_img, exists, list_files
from argparse import ArgumentParser
from collections import defaultdict
import time
import json
import subprocess
import numpy
from moviepy.video.io.VideoFileClip import VideoFileClip
import moviepy.video.io.ffmpeg_writer as ffmpeg_writer

BATCH_SIZE = 4
DEVICE = '/gpu:0'


def ffwd_video(path_in, path_out, checkpoint_dir, device_t='/gpu:0', batch_size=4):
    video_clip = VideoFileClip(path_in, audio=False)
    video_writer = ffmpeg_writer.FFMPEG_VideoWriter(path_out, video_clip.size, video_clip.fps, codec="libx264",
                                                    preset="medium", bitrate="2000k",
                                                    audiofile=path_in, threads=None,
                                                    ffmpeg_params=None)

    g = tf.Graph()
    soft_config = tf.compat.v1.ConfigProto(allow_soft_placement=True)
    soft_config.gpu_options.allow_growth = True
    with g.as_default(), g.device(device_t), \
            tf.compat.v1.Session(config=soft_config) as sess:
        batch_shape = (batch_size, video_clip.size[1], video_clip.size[0], 3)
        img_placeholder = tf.compat.v1.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=batch_shape,
                                         name='img_placeholder')

        preds = transform.net(img_placeholder)
        saver = tf.compat.v1.train.Saver()
        if os.path.isdir(checkpoint_dir):
            ckpt = tf.train.get_checkpoint_state(checkpoint_dir)
            if ckpt and ckpt.model_checkpoint_path:
                saver.restore(sess, ckpt.model_checkpoint_path)
            else:
                raise Exception("No checkpoint found...")
        else:
            saver.restore(sess, checkpoint_dir)
```

Thank you very much for your willingness to help
Thank you very much for your willingness to help
Thank you very much for your willingness to help

Comment: Hi @S J and welcome to our community!  
Could you please edit your question, elaborating it a little bit, giving us more detail and context?

Answer (score 0):

This error is coming from the program `evaluate.py` itself, which is apparently something you've written or downloaded, so we have no way to answer without seeing it.  However, judging by the error message alone,

```
the following arguments are required: --in-path, --out-path
```

I notice that in your command line,

```
python3 evaluate.py --checkpoint ./rain-princess.ckpt --in-path/Users/hassan/Downloads/fast-style-transfer-master--out-path ./output_image.jpg
```

you have neither of these because there is no space between `--in-path` and what's apparently meant to be its argument, and no space between this filename and `--out-path`.  So I'd try changing this to

```
python3 evaluate.py --checkpoint ./rain-princess.ckpt --in-path /Users/hassan/Downloads/fast-style-transfer-master --out-path ./output_image.jpg
```

and seeing if that moves things along.

If that doesn't fix it, we will need some context as to what `evaluate.py` is.